# How to return multiple rows of data from pandas df?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am doing an SQL like search through thousands of lines of an excel file. What i am using is working, but i now need to return all values and having a hard time figuring it out.

```
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|123467|123231|134521|Data00|Info00|Here00|
|976443|1224ff|14xec1|Data01|Info01|Here01|
|123467|12wf41|34qqa1|Data02|Info02|Here02|
```

I am using:

```
boolean = []
entry = 123467
dictionary_df = pd.read_excel(my_xlsx)
for col in range(3):
    for row in dictionary_df[dictionary_df.columns[col]]:
        if entry in str(row):
            boolean.append(True)
        else:
            boolean.append(False)
    if True in boolean:
        is_long = pd.Series(boolean)
        data1 = dictionary_df[is_long][Col4].values[0]
        data2 = dictionary_df[is_long][Col5].values[0]
        data3 = dictionary_df[is_long][Col6].values[0]
```

So what I am doing is searching all 3 columns, and making a list of True false, and then if it found the result, it grabs the data i need from column 4-6.  This works but it only returns the values from column 4,5,6 for the last one found, not both. What i need in this situation is to be able to have data1 be a list containing(Data00, Data02). I cannot figure out how to include both results (or many) from the way I am doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the vectorized solution you can try:

```py
entry = 123467

res = df.loc[
    df.iloc[:, :3].astype(str)\
    .replace(f".*{entry}.*", entry, regex=True)\
    .eq(entry).any(axis=1), df.columns[3:]\
]
```

For the first 3 columns - I regex replace everything matching `entry` inside with only `entry` (so if there's `entry` inside cell I replace the whole cell with just `entry`), then I filter out rows with at least one `entry` in it (you can do `arr == x` in a vectorized `numpy` way, but not `x in arr`), finally returning only latest 3 columns of these rows.

Outputs:

```py
     Col4    Col5    Col6
0  Data00  Info00  Here00
2  Data02  Info02  Here02
```

To convert the output per your requirement:

```py
data1,data2,data3=res.T.values
```

Which outputs:

```py
>>> print(data1,data2,data3)

['Data00' 'Data02'] ['Info00' 'Info02'] ['Here00' 'Here02']
```

Comment: I am having a hard time following this.... So your replacing most of my code with this?  res is going to be the results?  I understand the first df.iloc line, but I do not understand what the replace or .eq lines are doing.

Comment: Yes, so essentially you cannot vectorize `a in df` in a way that it validates each cell of `df` whether it has `a` in it. What I'm doing instead is to replace in every cell where there's `entry` in it, with just `entry` so `xyz<entry>abc`, `<entry>123` or `<entry>` will become just `entry` then you can do `df==a` and check `.any(axis=1)` which will essentially check the whole row, whether there's at least one `True`. You should see a difference in performance, because it's vectorized solution

Comment: So this seems to be the way I want to go, but I need to get the data from col4, col5, and col6. And I need the data to either be col4 = data00 or if there is multiple values col4 = (data00, data02, data55). I am struggling on how to pull the info from the pd df.

Comment: That's on top of this `entry` filter on col1-3, right? Can you clarify this a bit in more detail in your question?

Comment: @Lzypenguin try now - I added `data1,data2,data3` conversion per your requirement

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer has helped me a lot. I actually have a bunch of columns, and they arent in order. I am searching for matches from 6 columns, and then pulling data from 8 columns, including data from some of the ones I searched through. But with your help and examples I was able to get exactly what i needed! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach could be a query, but this was the first I managed to get to work. The results are in a dataframe, hope this suits your needs.
I commented what I did, its basically getting all the indices into a list and then getting only unique values.

No clue what happens performancewise, but this should be adaptable for you.

import pandas as pd

```
data = {
    'Col1' : [123467, 976443, 123467,976443,976443],
    'Col2' : [123231, 122400, 120041, 3647677, 23485],
    'Col3' : [134521, 141001, 3456123, 123467, 12376],
    'Col4' : ['Data00', 'Data01','Data02', 'Dataxy', 'Datablah'],
    'Col5' : ['Info00', 'Info02','Info03', 'Infoxy', 'Infoxz'],
    'Col6' : ['Here00','Here02','Here03', 'Here04', 'Here05'] 
}

entry = 123467
dictionary_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# concatenate lists where col1, col2 or col3 meet condition. 
indices = dictionary_df[dictionary_df['Col1'] == entry].index.tolist() + dictionary_df[dictionary_df['Col2'] == entry].index.tolist() + dictionary_df[dictionary_df['Col3'] == entry].index.tolist()
# might be duplicates. therefore make set of list (== get rid of doubles. Indices are uniqe, therefore we do not have loss of info)
result = set(indices)
# now get dataframe of col4-6 with only the rows that meet the indices
result = dictionary_df[['Col4', 'Col5', 'Col6']].loc[result]
print(result)
```

Outputs:

```
     Col4    Col5    Col6
0  Data00  Info00  Here00
2  Data02  Info03  Here03
3  Dataxy  Infoxy  Here04
```

Adding this to the code above

```
result_aslist_example = result['Col4'].values.tolist()
print(result_aslist_example)
```

The Output additionally contains:

```
['Data00', 'Data02', 'Dataxy']
```

Comment: This seems like exactly what I need to do. I assume the way your searching the columns int he DF is much more efficient than the way I am?

Comment: Also. I am reading an excel file with 10k+ rows of data. I am using pd.read_excel(). You are using pd.Dataframe. Is this going to be an issue?  Also you are doing if the value is equal to my entry, and I need is in the entry. Because some of the cells have a value of (1111111, 1112222, 11112221) and I need to return that row if entry is in the cell at all. Thanks

Comment: I chose pd.Dataframe to get an examplary Dataframe, so this shouldn't be an issue. We have different ways to get a dataframe but as the datalayout is similar, we can contiune the same. 
Regarding your 2nd question, I am not quite sure what you want to do. So the steps I took are the following: 1) Create Dataframe 2) Get Lists of Indices of Col1 where the value is equal to entry. 2a) Do this for Col2 and Col3 2b) Concatenate that lists (If you copy my code and add print indices, you will notice what I mean) 3) get set of it (set has only unique values) 4) get rows of dfwith index in result

Comment: The code is the full program I run, so you can just copy&paste it and try to adjust it for your needs. If it does as intended, just replace my pd.DataFrame by your read_exel. 
For efficency: I have no clue but I think build-in search in pandas is most of the time faster than anything you could do?